# Read an excel file on asp.net core 1.0

Tags: c#, excel, import, asp.net-core-1.0

Hello I`m trying to upload and read an excel file on my asp.net project but all the documentation I find is for ASP MVC 5.
My goal is to read the excel sheet and pass the values to an list of objects.

This is my controller, it works for upload the file to my wwwroot/uploads

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public IActionResult index()
    {
        return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads,    file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Open the [package manager console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) in Visual Studio and type:

```
PM> Install-Package EPPlus.Core
```

Writing files is then as simple as:

```
public void WriteExcel(string fileName)
{


    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);
    /// overwrite old file
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        file.Delete();
        file = new FileInfo(fileName);
    }
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
        // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employee");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "HELLO WORLD!!!";
        package.Save(); 
    }
}
```

More examples here: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-xlsx-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 3):

In .NET Core OleDb and DataTables are gone. This makes it harder for some projects to port themselves to netcore.

If you're reading OpenXml Excel files (xlsx), the unofficial Epplus.Core can help you.

But for the older 97-2003 formats (xls) we couldn't find a solution yet.

I would hope either NPOI or ExcelDataReader would get a core version later this year, but i don't see much activity on that direction.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in some comments and answers, there is an unnoficial EPPlus port to .Net Core (I've checked right now and it supports Core 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0)...

This code demonstrates how to do it

```
var filePath = @"D:/test.xlsx";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{       
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
    int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

    var rawText = string.Empty;
    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= ColCount; col++)
        {   
            // This is just for demo purposes
            rawText += worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t";    
        }
        rawText+="\r\n";
    }
    _logger.LogInformation(rawText);
}
```

Note: today I used at work and I created a dictionary mathing column numbers with column names to access directly to each column, given the name, row by row and the performance was better than using some other libraries aimed to read csv files.

Few links:

- EPPlus.Core: https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core
- A HowTo with this concrete example:
  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1217036/Console-Logging-and-Reading-Excel-Files-with-NET-C

I hope it helps,

Juan

Answer (score 1):

Add the following package:

```
Install-Package Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core -Version 17.2.0.49
```

Method to read excel file:

```
 private DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable(string path)
    {
            using (Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
                {
                    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
                    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inputStream);
                    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                    DataTable dataTable = worksheet.ExportDataTable(worksheet.UsedRange, ExcelExportDataTableOptions.ColumnNames);
                    return dataTable;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this requires a [$995/dev/yr license](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/fileformats) ... imma pass

Answer (score -2):

In most cases it does not matter if you are using ASP.NET 4 or ASP.NET Core when it comes to reading Excel files. You just need to find a library that allows to do that. It is recommended to use NuGet to add such libraries into your project.

See instructions how to install a NuGet package here: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/install-nuget

One library that I can recommend to use is EPPlus (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus).

When you are done with file uploading and have stored Excel file somewhere, you just need to open it using EPPlus for reading. Simple example follows:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("sample.xlsx"));

ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; i++)
{
    for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row; j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; j++)
    {
        object cellValue = workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: EPPlus is not supported on .NET Core but there is an unofficial port of EPPlus library named EPPlus.core which can be used to read and write excel. See this [link](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-xlsx-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I would say it does matter especially if you are trying to read xls or password protected Excel files. Most packages use depreciated data structures such as datatables or ole connection providers that are not implemented in Core. Also password protected files need Office com libraries for read/write operations.